# How to realise a belongsToThrough relationship in Laravel 9 / 10?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9, eloquent-relationship

There are three models: Employer, Instance, Worker.

The important fillables of the models are:

- **Employer**

  - company_name
- **Instance**

  - worker_id
  - employer_id
- **Worker**

  - name

In consequence I have:

```php
class Employer {
    public function instances()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Instance::class);
    }
}
```

```php
class Instance {
    public function worker()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Worker::class);
    }

    public function employer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Employer::class);
    }
}
```

What I want to have is something like

```php
class Worker {
    public function employer()
    {
        return $this->belongsToThrough(Instance::class, Employer::class);
    }
}
```

but this function does not exist.
The SQL would be:

```sql
select e.company
from employers e
join instances i on i.employer_id = e.id
join workers w on w.id = i.worker_id
where w.id = ?
```

Finally I want to be able to use:

```php
$workers_company = Worker::find(1)->employer->company_name;
```

Comment: Try [hasOneThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-one-through) instead?

Comment: This would be a 1:many relationship and I'd need to use `$worker->employer->first()->company`

Comment: No, a one-to-one is hasOneThrough, a one-to-many would be a [hasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through). `The "has-one-through" relationship defines a one-to-one relationship with another model. However, this relationship indicates that the declaring model can be matched with one instance of another model by proceeding through a third model.`

Comment: You are right. If you would mind adding it as the answer, I can vote it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `hasOneThrough` relationship, with the final table/class as the first parameter, and the intermediate table/class as the second parameter (has one Employer through an Instance).

```
class Worker {
    public function employer()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(Employer::class, Instance::class);
    }
}
```